# AccessDenied executable in AWS Lambda Layer - FFMPEG

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, chmod

I have an FFMPEG executable as a Lambda Layer, deployed with Serverless framework. Unfortunately I'm not able to execute it, getting AccessDenied & EACCESS errors.

I'm tried fixing it with FS-CHMOD like the following:

```
chmodSync('/opt/ffmpeg/ffmpeg', 0o100);
```

And getting this error:

```
Error EROFS: read-only file system, chmod '/opt/ffmpeg/ffmpeg'
```

My question is... what now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone on Windows (like me) who finds this in future - Lambda file permissions are set outside of Lambda, and you'll need to boot a Linux VM (or a Mac) to change CHMOD stuff on files that will end up on Lambda.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write to anything but `/tmp` in a Lambda *or* you need to mount an EFS filesystem.  You will need to change the deployment location of the `ffmpeg` executable.

See [this documentation for /tmp](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-context.html) or [this link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-a-shared-file-system-for-your-lambda-functions/) for information on mounting an EFS volume.

Comment: For the record this really helped! I'm on Windows mostly so CHMOD stuff is pretty foreign to me, so I went down the rabbit hole and found that CHMOD permissions need to be set locally for Lambda, something that's not possible on Windows unless you set up a Linux VM. Thanks!